# How to use async / await using react-native-router-flux

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native-router-flux

I'm using firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged to check if the user is signed in. IF yes THEN route to userProfile ELSE route to login. Since this is an asynchronous action, I'm trying to make it work using async and await with react-native-router-flux where onEnter, firebase checks if user is signed in. Once the result is returned, react-native-router flux routes the user correctly.

Here is my code that automatically render the "fail" condition instead of waiting for the loggedIn object that is not null (it would return as true or false).

```
class RouterComponent extends Component {
  currentAuthStatus = async () => {
    this.props.checkLoginStatus();
    await this.props.loggedIn !== null;
  };
 render() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
        <Scene key="auth">
          <Scene key="loadingPage" component={LoadingPage} hideNavBar on={() => this.currentAuthStatus()} success="userProfile" failure="login" />
        <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Login" />
      </Scene>
      <Scene key="main">
        <Scene key="userProfile" component={UserProfile} title="Profile" />
       </Scene>
     </Scene>

   </Router>
);
```

}
}

Comment: Hi. Did you solve this issue? I need same approach.